# Using LINQ, how can I filter a collection on partial string property?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a collection of Car objects,

```
IEnumerable<Car>
```

And I want to return a filtered collection of car objects, based on a partial string match (it doesn't have to be startswith) where the Car.Name property has certain text in it.

Is this possible using LINQ?

Comment: Instead of string.Contains, you could use IndexOf if you want a case-insensitive search, so you can pass a StringComparison value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from c in cars
where c.Name.Contains("certain text")
select c
```

or

```
cars.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("certain text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars = ...
var filteredCars = cars.Where(car => car.Name.Contains("your text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
var cars = new List<Car>(); //Or whatever makes sense.

var filteredCars = cars.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("searchstring"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want:

```
var filteredCars = cars.Where(car => car.Name.Contains("Fiesta"));
```

You can increase the complexity of the predicate as you wish.

Comment: Hehe, yes indeed. Without Intelisense I wasn't sure if Contains existed, so I played it safe.

Comment: Also how do you know you should .ToArray() the collection?

Comment: sounds like its more correct after all(with a little tweak) :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring/444818#444818

Comment: @stilgar: i meant the answer not your comment. your point is very valid :)

Comment: The ToArray() is on there for no particular reason. I'll remove it to make the example more concise.